# Unity 3D Performance Issues with 3D Models

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, blender, 3dsmax, sketchup

I'm trying to develop a Vuforia Augmented Reality Project on Unity 3D. One of my friends is providing me a construction's 3D Model on different formats like .FBX .3DS and .blend

We have a huge trouble with performance. When we use .blend files, even models with higher poly are OK but low poly models of .FBX .3DS formats are running slower.

So, i think we have to use .blend models but what my friend does on google sketch-up is losing it's textures and color when he open them on Blender.

In conclusion, my question is how can we create good construction models on Unity 3D with its texture ? Do we have to build all the model on blender ? Can't i simply convert models build on Google Sketch-up or 3DStudioMax to .blend files with its textures and colors.

Comment: All 3D models are converted to FBX during import in Unity. So I guess something goes wrong during FBX export from 3DS. Are you sure that the model in Unity is really low poly? The mesh object in Unity shows the number of vertices and tris in preview. Another point might be that the material which is created during import is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

My performance issues fixed with using Occlusion Culling and LOD support on unity 3d pro version. You can find many details about those topics on unity3d website guys :)

Comment: That may have fixed your issues, but what Kay commented is still true - Unity uses .fbx only.

Comment: yes, i agree with him. But i realized that what my problem is about complexity of my model.